# How can I use Stack Exchange as notes repository?

Tags: discussion

I have tried mails to self and text files to keeping notes in one place, which I can reuse. However I have found them getting lost as time passes by. The "Answer your own question" in Stack Exchange is good way of keeping notes to self. However if the question is simple e.g. "how to do something", Stack Exchange does not allow to post the question. I was wondering if there are guidelines to post simple questions with answer, which I and others can use.

Comment: Meant to post it to meta exchange and not meta-stackoverflow. Here is the link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237950/how-can-i-use-stackexchange-as-notes-repository

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross-posted on Meta SE. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237950/1288

Comment: You don't. Learn to dump code where code belongs.

Comment: The answer is located at: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 7):

Stack Exchange is a network of question and answer sites, not a notes repository. It does not exist to be all things to all people.

If you need to take notes then take notes and store them somewhere else.

If you have a *good* question (according to the guidelines) then please ask it. If you are able to answer it as well then that's brilliant but its not a requirement.

Comment: You are essentially saying, that personal notes are okay - until they follow the Q&A format and quality / topic requirements. Why should have you formulated it in such a rejective tone? Reading your answer, the literal meaning is that self-answered questions are welcomed, but anybody reading it will surely lose all motivation to write one.

Answer (score 1):

There are many available sources online for keeping notes in one place accessible from any device (i.e. Google Drive), and the "how do I do this" questions are best either done by researching them yourself or using a forum.

Comment: [There is no inherent problem with "how do I" questions in general!](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1078119/how-do-i-questions)